# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED CodeIgniter when access from another device in local network

Tags: codeigniter

I have some code built in Codeigniter 4, all my assets load correctly, but I have some issue when the web access from another device in local network, the assets can't load and got some error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image: Error like this when i access from another device]

My base_url `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:96/sun/'`

This is how I call my assets:

```
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>/public/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

When I run from my web server:

```
<script src="http://localhost:96/sun/public/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

What I expected running from another device:

```
<script src="http://(ip web server):96/sun/public/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

But running like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:96/sun/public/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

So, the assets can't load correctly.

Comment: `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:96/sun/` so you need to specify the ip instead of localhost. like this in `app.baseurl =http://192.1681.100:96/sun` .the ip is your systems ip

Comment: i was try it before, and it's work, but can i make the ip address dynamicly? or change the setting in codeigniter? thank before